# Models to multidimensional Array

Tags: php, yii

I am kind of new to the `Yii` framework and this is about finding the best solution, **I know you can achieve this with loops and all, but I'm trying to find a better solution** (if there is one).

```
Structure (example):
    Tv: id, price, size_id, brand_id
    Brand: id, name
    Size: id, inch, cm
```

So now I am trying to create a grid where the rows will be the `Brands` (ex.: samsung, sony, lg) and the columns represent the `Sizes` (ex: 20", 30",...) and the cells will have the `Price` as the value...

```
           40"   44"   48"  50"
Brand1   $200  $240  $280  320  
Brand2   $180  $220  $240  300  
Brand3   $210  $230  $270  350
```

Again, I am searching for the best solution to do this using `Yii`/`PHP`.

Comment: When you say grid you are talking about a CGridView or your own grid? For me you can achieve it with a single Sql query

Comment: Now I was using my own grid, do you recommend using CGridView?

Comment: Don't know what your own grid is, but I think the easiest way is to use a custom sql request without ActiveRecord

Answer (score 0):

In this case, SQL created with `CSqlDataProvider`.

Example here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSqlDataProvider

If your grid is not derived from `CGridView`, you should consider using `CGridView` or rewriting your grid. `CGridView` gives you pagination and ajax navigation out of the box. `CGridView` will be also easily extensible, you can move your tables to bootstrap without pain in the future for example.

If you want to use `CActiveRecord`, you can do this in following way:

1. Add getters for sizes or rewrite `__get()` in `Brand`:

> ```
> public function get30InchPrice() {
>    $elems = $this->tvs(array('condition' => 'size_id=:e', 'params' => array('e' => 1)));
>    foreach($elems as $v) return $v->price;
>    return 0;
> }
> ```

1. Add names to `attributeLabels()`
2. Configure `CGridView` to use your special properties:

> ```
> $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
>     'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
>     'columns'=>array(
>         '30InchPrice',
>         '40InchPrice',
>     ), ));
> ```